# Puppies chewed through the cord on airconditioner in the window. I rewired color to color. It still is popping in wire fuse

Tags: electrical

I have rewired things before. And this isn't new. I have never encountered this before!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Something must have changed, and we can't figure out what without some more information. So, please take another close look at your wiring and let us know what you see.

Comment: I would continue looking for damage on the cord.  A small puncture could have the hot shorted to one of the other conductors with very little visible damage. Many years ago my son got a Beagle this little bugger wiped out several cords until he finally got whacked hard enough to quit chewing them, there was at least 1 that I could not find the damage but the cord showed shorted with my ohm meter requiring the cord cap to be very short and a extension used because it was heavy and I did not want to pull it out and replace the whole thing.

Comment: You're not going to believe this. I saw on place might have happened. Cut and spliced a little more. But I suspect this is what really happened. As I was splicing I noticed they used metal fiber threads in the insulation between the insulated wires. A few threads could have been grafted into the splice. I was VERY careful this time lol what nonsense is this?

Comment: It's a protective device mandated because a lot of people were being hurt by the lack of that protective device. A/C units are vulnerable to ground faults because their apparatus lives outside. The third ground prong would take care of that problem if the ground is intact, but window A/C's are often used in older housing stock, very often old tenant units with 2-wire branch circuits. If bootlegged into a groundless connection, the ground fault would simply electrify the air conditioner chassis. I would say defeat the device if unneeded, but what happens when you sell it on craigslist?

Comment: It not only comes with the third prong. There is a default fuse in line built into the chord.

Comment: Cord.. Stupid auto correct

Answer (score 2):

**Popping in wire fuse?**  Is the unit actually connected to a fuse or some sort of breaker or tripping device. All AC units with cords that I know of come with a GFCI device at the cord cap. Is this tripping? If it is, pay attention to @EdBeals comment. GFCI's are very sensitive and you really don't have to have a short. You just have to have some sort of current leakage.

I would recommend you try and order a new cord from the manufacturer or an aftermarket cord and replace the whole thing.

Good luck.

Comment: I just was careful this time and it works again. Thank you